# FFmpeg command line CPU usage vs code CPU usage

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

On my existing PC/IP Camera combination, the command line function

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://abcd:123456@1.2.3.4/rtspvideostream /home/pc/video.avi
```

correctly writes the video stream to file and uses approximately 30% of my CPU.

The command line function

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://abcd:123456@1.2.3.4/rtspvideostream -vcodec copy /home/pc/video.avi
```

uses approximately 3% of my CPU for seemingly the same result. I assume the removal of some functionality related to the codec contributes to this CPU saving.

Using the following standard ffmpeg initialisation:

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx;
AVDictionary *opts = NULL;
av_dict_set(&opts, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx,"rtsp://abcd:123456@1.2.3.4/rtspvideostream", NULL, &opts);
avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx,NULL);
int videoStream = -1;
for(int i=0; i<(int)pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
{
  if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type== AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
  {
    videoStream=i;
    break;
  }
}
pCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL)
AVFrame *pFrame = av_frame_alloc();
int numBytes = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, IMAGEWIDTH, IMAGEHEIGHT);
uint8_t *buffer12 = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));
avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrame, buffer12, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, IMAGEWIDTH, IMAGEHEIGHT);
```

with the standard reading implementation:

```
int frameFinished = 0;
while(frameFinished == 0)
{
  av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet);
  if(packet.stream_index==videoStream)
  {
    avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
  }
  if( packet.duration ) av_free_packet(&packet);
  packet.duration = 0;
}
```

correctly gets the video stream and uses approximately 30% of CPU.

In the command-line ffmpeg implementation, the addition of the parameters '-vcodec copy' dramatically decreases CPU usage. I am unable to reproduce a similar drop in CPU usage for the above coding implementation.

Assuming it is possible, how do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The `-vcodec copy` implies that the video stream is copied as is (it is not being decoded/encdoed) so the CPU usage is pure I/O. To do the same you should remove all the codec opening stuff and decoding (`avcodec_decode_video2`) from your code and just write the packet directly to the output stream.